# Single-Column Indexing in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

There is a field:

```
#[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true, )]
private ?string $inn = null;
```

How to add single-column indexing through migrations to avoid errors in Symfony.

I tried to find documentation about this on the official doctrine website, but found only info about relations indexes between entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the class, add something like this

```php
#[ORM\Index(columns: ['inn'], name: 'application_inn_idx')]
```

Then generate a migration

```
symfony console make:migration
```

And then run the migration

```
symfony console doctrine:migration:migrate
```